# Windows Phone native std::cout

Tags: c#, c++, logging, windows-phone-8, native

I have a windows phone application which uses my own Windows Phone Runtime Component which has native C++ code in it. This is working fine. My problem now is that for easier error finding and debugging I want to see my logs from C++.

I have in my C++ code:

```
void MyNativeCPPClass::outputTest()
    std::cout << "Testing \n";
    std::cout << std::flush;
}
```

Now I do not see this output. My guess is, that it is send to a console and I don't see a console in a Windows Phone App. There I just have my output window. I have read about a [ConsoleTraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.consoletracelistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I don't know how to configure it for windows phone. If that is even possible.

So I would like to know if I can somehow append my C++ `std::cout` to my Output window in my Windows Phone App? Or if that is not possible. How could I do log directly from C++, so that I can somehow see it in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do this for debugging purposes, I would recommend using [`OutputDebugString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362(VS.85).aspx). Anything you output with this will appear in the Debug Output dialog in Visual Studio when it's attached to your Windows Phone app.

Make sure you attach the [native debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289770/windows-phone-log-to-console) for this to work.