# How to get device logs from Windows devices_

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, logging, mobile

Im working at mobile games area as a QA Engineer. We develop mobile games for Android, iOs and Windows. And now we have a question: how to get logs from Windows devices(tablets,phones).

Is there any program like iTools(or iPhone Configuration Utility) for iOs or ddms for Android, but for Windows? Somebody know how can i get device logs from Win tablet for example?

We need to get logs from app launch(game).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you expect to see the Log output?

You can try to use [Debug.WriteLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, for example :

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Print something");
```

to print some value to Visual Studio output window.

Have a look here [Windows Phone: Log to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289770) too.

Hope it helps :)